# C# como Selecionar e Colorir todo texto dentro de uma determinada linha no RichTextbox?

Tags: c#, select, richtextbox

No C# tenho um RichTextbox, dentro dele tem varias linhas, o que quero fazer é selecionar todo texto dentro de uma determinada linha e colorir. o que estou fazendo é o seguinte:

```
richTextBox1.Select(0, richTextBox1.Lines[index].Length);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

O zero é a posição inicial do texto, o index é o numero da linha e o Lenght é o que vai dizer qual será o fim da seleção dentro desta linha.

O problema é que não seleciona o texto da linha atual, ele sempre seleciona o texto da primeira linha.

Para ficar mais claro, eu preciso fazer neste estilo:

```
1
2
3 eu quero selecionar todo esse texto
4
```

Como posso pegar a corrente de uma determinada linha do richTextBox e dentro desta corrente selecionar todo texto? e não "somente" a primeira linha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o método [GetFirstCharIndexFromLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline(v=vs.110).aspx) para obter a posição em que uma determinada linha se inicia.

Para mudar a cor da linha, faça assim:

```
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(index),
                    richTextBox1.Lines[index].Length);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```